# Unable to open pycharm on raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, pi-4, python-3

when i type ./pycharm.sh in terminal it throughs the following error:
"Error occured during intialization of VM
java/lang/ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 101 in class file java/lang/Appendable"

my pycharm folder is in "/opt" and i'm already in that directory

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassFormatError.html ...Something got screwed up with the install, perhaps.

Comment: i am unable to unzip it properly in my rpi-4, i'm trying since 2 days and i'm facing the same error,it got unzipped for once but it won't run throws the above error

Comment: PyCharm is Java based. As far as I remember it should contain on own JRE it can use but may be it tries to use an outdated installed JRE? Make sure an OpenJDK JRE or JDK is installed, e.g. OpenJDK 11 (the common LTS Java Version at the moment) and selected as default JRE.

Comment: i already have default jdk installed in my raspberry pi